# Tabstops in Ultisnips not working properly with zsh

Tags: bash, vim, zsh, ultisnips

I recently switched from bash to zsh and now the tabstops in my Ultisnips-snippets aren't working properly anymore.

I didn't change anything in my snippet files and after I encountered the problem for the first time, I went back to bash, started vim from there and the snippets worked as intended again.

I have these to snippets

```
snippet ( iA
($1)$0
endsnippet

snippet mk wA
$$1$$0
endsnippet
```

If I run vim from bash and type `mk`, it will expand to

```
$Cursor$
```

(I will denote the cursor position by `Cursor`). Then I can type `f(` and it will expand to

```
$f(Cursor)$
```

If I press `x` and then `tab` it will take me to

```
$f(x)Cursor$
```

(I will call this previous step **S**). Pressing `tab` again I will arrive at

```
$f(x)$Cursor
```

Running vim from zsh however, I can still do the steps until **S** but if I then press `tab`, it will stay at

```
$f(x)Cursor$
```

and start inserting tabs after that. If I only do `mk` however and type something else without brackets, for example `ab`

```
$abCursor$
```

and then press `tab`, it will work as expected and get me to

```
$ab$Cursor
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going on here? What can I do if I want to keep using zsh and Ultisnips? If I run `bash -c 'vim file.txt'`, vim will work really slowly and lag a lot, so that is not really an option.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Apparently the problem has something to do with what version of vim I'm using. I use macOS and the problem I described happens when I use the default vim version. If I use a custom-compiled version of vim, it works as expected. And as it turns out I have some config file that tells bash to use the custom-compiled version, whereas zsh still uses the default one. I also tried it on my PC (running Ubuntu) and with the vim version installed there, it also worked. So I guess, I'll use my custom-compiled vim to avoid this problem...

But does anybody know, what vim setting could be responsible for this? If I'm not mistaken my custom-compiled version is just the huge-feature version of vim.

Comment: I can only assume you have some `vim`-specific setup in a `bash` configuration file that doesn't appear in your `zsh` configuration files.

Comment: @chepner I get the same behavior with `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` empty

Comment: Is the value of `$TERM` the same in both shells? I can't really think of anything about `zsh` that would affect the behavior of `vim`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it is `xterm-256color`

Comment: @chepner You were right with your first comment, that it is some vim-specific option that is different in my bash and zsh config. It wasn't set in my standard bash config file though. That is why I didn't see it at first.